# Write an interpreter for my new esoteric language PointerLang

Tags: code-golf, interpreter

I designed a language in which pointer arithmetic is the main tool of programming.

Here are some examples.

```
(print 0 to 8)
=9[>1=9-*-1.>-1-1]

(print 1 to 10 with spaces in between, character literal extension used)
=1[.>1=10-*-1[>1=' '!>-2+1;-2];1]='\n'!

(compute the factorial of 10)
=10>1=*-1-1[>-1**1>1-1]>-1.

(print "hi")
=104!=105!

(print "hi" with extension for arrays)
={104,105,0}[!>1]

(print "Hello, world!" with extension for C-style string literals)
="Hello, world!"[!>1]
```

### Language Specification

The language definition is very simple. You will understand very easily if you have experience with C, but I will not assume so.

Every program in PointerLang has *the pointer*, in short, `P`. You can think it as a hidden single global variable, which you can control by using *commands*. `P` initially *points to* the beginning of *the array*. Every element in the array has the type `int` which is a 32-bit signed integer.

For C programmers

```
int32_t *P = malloc(1000);
```

In PointerLang, there are *commands* and *arguments*. An argument is an `int` which must come after a command. All commands are executed from left to right unless specified otherwise. The following is the list of commands. `A` stands for argument. A command without `A` means it does not take an argument. A command with `A` must take an argument. Inside the parentheses is the equivalent C expression.

- `=A` : assign A at P (`*P = A`)
- `+A` : add A at P (`*P += A`)
- `-A` : subtract A at P (`*P -= A`)
- `*A` : multiply by A at P (`*P *= A`)
- `/A` : divide by A at P (`*P /= A`)
- `>A` : move `P` by `A` (`P += A`)
- `.` : print the integer at P (`printf("%d", *P)`)
- `!` : print the integer at P as ASCII (`printf("%c", (char)*P)`)
- `[` : if the value at P is 0 go to the command after the next `]` (`while (*P) {`)
- `]` : go to the previous `[` that is the matching pair (`}`)
- `;A` : if `A` is positive, go to the command after the `A`th `]` coming next; if `A` is negative, go to the `A`th `[` coming before; if A is 0, do nothing.

An integer literal is an argument.

The following two are special arguments that take an argument.

- `-A` : evaluated as an argument having the same absolute value as `A` and the opposite sign of `A`; unary minus
- `*A` : move `P` by `A`, evaluate the value at `P`, move `P` by `-A` (`P[A]`)

All comments in PointerLang are between parentheses `(comment)`.

### Example Program

This program which counts from 1 to 10 is a good example to complete your understanding.

```
(print 1 to 10 with spaces in between)
=1[.>1=10-*-1[>1=32!>-2+1;-2];1]=10!
```

Be careful when you interpret `-*-1`. `-` is the command and `*-1` is the argument. An integer literal effectively indicates the end of a command-argument pair.

It can be translated to C with 1-to-1 correspondence as

```
int main(void) {
    int32_t *P = malloc(1000);
    *P = 1; // =1
l:
    while (*P) { // [
        printf("%d", *P); // .
        P += 1; // > 1
        *P = 10; // =10
        *P -= P[-1]; // -*-1
        while (*P) { // [
            P += 1; // >1
            *P = 32; // =32
            printf("%c", (char)*P); // !
            P += -2; // >-2
            *P += 1; // +1
            goto l; // ;-2
        } // ]
        break; // ;1
    } // ]
    *P = 10; // =10
    printf("%c", (char)*P); // !
    return 0;
}
```

Extensions can be applied to this language such as character literals, arrays, string literals etc, but you don't have to implement them, for simplicity.

### The Challenge

You have to implement the core features detailed in the *Language Specification* section and the NOTEs below. Give it a try with your favourite programming language, writing the shortest program possible.

NOTE1: The size of *the array* is undefined. But it should be big enough to solve most problems.

NOTE2: Integer overflow is undefined.

NOTE3: The specification only defines the result or effect of certain language constructs. For example, you don't have to exactly follow the steps in the definition of the argument `*`.

NOTE4: <s>Any characters that are not commands, arguments, or comments</s> Whitespaces are ignored. `=104!=105!` is as same as `= 1 0  4!   = 1 05    !` for example.

NOTE5: Comments are not nested. `((comment))` is a syntax error.

NOTE6: I've made a breaking change to fix a hole in my language. The `~` command is now unused and `;` always takes an argument.

NOTE7: Every integer literal is decimal.

Comment: Is it just me or is this basically brainfuck?

Comment: can we assume all statements passed are valid? ie all braces are closed

Comment: Are you sure the first example `=9[>1=9-*-1.>-1-1]` prints 0 to 9?  After it ptints 8 because P[0]=1 it then subtracts 1 just before the end of the loop which makes P[0]=0 and then when it starts the loop again it should exit because P[0]=0 so the example should only print 0 to 8.  Or am I just really confused?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah hmm.. sure it seems like my mistake, will fix now.

Comment: This is like what BrainFuck wanted to be.

Comment: Does infinite output have to be supported?

Answer (score 3):

## C 406

**Thanks to @ceilingcat for some very nice pieces of golfing - now even shorter**

```
#define L strtol(I++,0,0)
#define A*I==42?I++,P[L]:L
#define F(a)-91-a|i;i-=*I-93+a?*I==91+a:-1);}
i,c;char*I;X[999],*P=X;Y(){for(;*I++F(2)B(){for(i=!--I;*--I F(0)main(j,a)int**a;{for(I=a[1];j=*I++;printf(j-4?j+9?j==19?*P=A:j==1?*P+=A:j==3?*P-=A:!j?*P*=A:j==5?*P/=A:j==20?P+=A:j-17?j-51?j-49?I=j+2?I:index(I,41)+1:*P||Y(i=1):B():({for(c=A;c;c+=c<0?:-1)if(i=c<1)B();else for(;*I++F(2)),"":P:"%d",*P))j-=42;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBNa@MwEIbv/RWKS0EfVutxUhZJVUX2UDDkkGOL8UGrKK1E65TE0ELT3@4dJ7sLexke5p2vd4J8DmEcLzdxm/pIVuQw7IfdK22EKKuyYhd/lSVvrF3UbhLW7arTq3/SA/VMKpD@mEySljdSzYV3U4MC4bUEZr4vUhlMePF73pjHVinVlXxtH80TZV/b3Z4ajpMfaM1@/kkkO5OyMRwDbqjYm089zaVnqR849@ZU1FjfQmeynbrN@x61Lc1y4bJQLlsLyuGWpZ4QSZxxjigRZxmBn3O3iDdnrCt3rpTww2V5CxgWyjU2C/SvU7@Jn7QpF8AEaL4@Hp/wWGAaL9f0dFawS4NuhQ13lZv8py2WhDuY3Jn4eojkP8@sLAq91sXVpsCvMJYlvtp8j@NY0JMpAmTYEajIRxpeyOHdh3ggqSe/4vARY88stNf3YKGSXEKLNK9n97IWYGTdGehQmRW/AQ)

and the slightly less golfed version of my original answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define L strtol(I++,&I,10)
#define A *I=='*'?I++,P[L]:L
int X[999],*P=X;
int main(int i, char *a[])
{
  char* I=a[1];
  while(*I)
  {
    switch(*I++)
    {
      case '(': while(*I++!=')'); break;
      case '.': printf("%d",*P); break;
      case '!': printf("%c",(char*)*P); break;
      case '[': if(!*P)
                  for(i=1;*I++!=']'||i;)
                  {
                    if(*I=='[')
                      i+=1;
                    if(*I==']')
                      i-=1;
                  }
                break;
      case ']': for(--I,i=0;*--I !='['||i;)
                {
                  if(*I==']')
                    i+=1;
                  if(*I=='[')
                    i-=1;
                }
                break;
      case '=': *P=A; break;
      case '+': *P+=A; break;
      case '-': *P-=A; break;
      case '*': *P*=A; break;
      case '/': *P/=A; break;
      case '>': P+=A; break;
      case ';': for(int c=A; c; c+=c<0?1:-1)
                {
                  if(c>0)
                    for(i=0;*I++!=']'||i;)
                    {
                      if(*I=='[')
                        i+=1;
                      if(*I==']')
                        i-=1;
                    }
                  else
                    for(--I,i=0;*--I !='['||i;)
                    {
                      if(*I==']')
                        i+=1;
                      if(*I=='[')
                        i-=1;
                    }
                }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ceilingcat  Ok, now ungolfing isn't possible any more so I have no idea how it works.  How do you keep making it shorter?

Comment: Just replaced `switch(...){case'(':...case'.':...` with `j=='('?...:j=='.'?...` and factored out function calls to fit within the ternary operator.

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks for all the golfing - I have learned a heap.

Comment: @ceilingcat  I didn't even know you could do that in C - I had to look it up.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6) - 560 bytes

Uses `prompt()` for input and `alert()` for output. It could be shortened if `alert()` was called for every character instead but I decided it would be better to buffer the characters so they could all be displayed at once.

```
b=[],d=0,e=[],f=0,g="",h="",k=prompt().replace(/(\s+|\(.*\))/g,""),l=0;n=()=>{m=g;if(m&&(a=m.substr(1),c=m.charAt(),a="*"==a.charAt()?b[d+parseInt(a.substr(1))]:parseInt(a),"["==c&&(b[d]?e.push(f-1):l++),"]"==c&&l&&(0<l&&(f=e.pop()),0>l&&(l=-l),l--),!l&&("="==c&&(b[d]=a),"+-*/".includes(c)&&eval("b[d]"+c+"=a"),">"==c&&(d+=a),"."==c&&(h+=b[d]),"!"==c&&(h+=String.fromCharCode(b[d])),";"==c&&(0<a&&(l=-l-a),0>a))))for(i=0;i<-a;i++)f=e.pop()}
for(f=0;f<k.length;f++)0<f&&"=+-*/>.![];".includes(k[f])&&k[f-1].match(/[0-9.!\[\]]/)&&(n(),g=""),g+=k[f];h&&alert(h);
```